# xcopy unc file not found

Tags: dos, xcopy

I am attempting to execute xcopy command that copies a file from one UNC path to another but I keep getting file not found error.  Using windows file explorer I know the path is correct and the file name exists but the error persists.  What gives?

```
C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe "\\MySourceShare\MyFolder1\MyFolder2\MyFolder3\MyFolder4\MyFolder5\filename" "\\MyDestShare\MyFolder1\filename" /Y
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This now works after a lot of permission debugging.  For the record you CAN copy files using UNC.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem only way to solve it was to use IP addres instead of machine name in the UNC path